# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Calling application did not provide package name

Tags: java, android, package, illegalargumentexception

```
Line 9942: 01-05 10:25:05.883  1084  2978 E ActivityManager: isInstantApp with an application's uid, no record, and no package name
Line 9943: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager: Activity Manager Crash. UID:1000 PID:1084 TRANS:8
Line 9944: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Calling application did not provide package name
Line 9945: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.isInstantApp(ActivityManagerService.java:19884)
Line 9946: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20320)
Line 9947: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.HwActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(HwActivityManagerService.java:4154)
Line 9948: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:21127)
Line 9949: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
Line 9950: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3282)
Line 9951: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at com.android.server.am.HwActivityManagerService.onTransact(HwActivityManagerService.java:832)
Line 9952: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 E ActivityManager:    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:675)
Line 9953: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Calling application did not provide package name
Line 9954: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.isInstantApp(ActivityManagerService.java:19884)
Line 9955: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20320)
Line 9956: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.HwActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(HwActivityManagerService.java:4154)
Line 9957: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:21127)
Line 9958: 01-05 10:25:05.884  1084  2978 W System.err:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
Line 9959: 01-05 10:25:05.885  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3282)
Line 9960: 01-05 10:25:05.885  1084  2978 W System.err:     at com.android.server.am.HwActivityManagerService.onTransact(HwActivityManagerService.java:832)
Line 9961: 01-05 10:25:05.885  1084  2978 W System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:675)
```

Hey, I rewrote some reflection function to avoid hidden functions and here it comes my app's starting to crash after I changed the SystemProperties to reflection function.
Any ideas please? What's the error of this